# Understand how transactions work when minting NFT

Tags: transactions, nft

very newbie question, but I tried to mint an NFT on https://www.developerdao.com/mint and when I did my metamask wallet showed me a transaction to confirm, I confirm and then the transaction was successful (https://etherscan.io/tx/0x68c3f22d27e94c6cef6a843777844acf65dd9746ad3cfd74768530d9e63f5143) but just after than metamask popped up again to confirm a second transaction? I didn't understand so I just confirmed and that failed (https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8d9dc01f55f5a824bc257be4809389be6d51637707692ad1018bbd37c1f61b1a)
My questions are, why were there 2 transactions and not one? How can I know beforehand how many transactions I'll have to approve (gas is expensive!)
And also, given that the last transaction failed, does it mean I lost the gas money for both of them?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your second transaction failed because it went out of gas: `Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]`.

I believe that you have your first NFT with id *4562* in your wallet, that is the first mint transaction, so it executed properly.

The second Metamask pop-up could be just bug on a front-end, or you may press a mint button several times and it was procession in sequence.

So if you want just one token, you should be fine right now. You unfortunately lost the gas of the second transaction.